# Assetic give me an FilterException since I update to Fedora25

Tags: php, node.js, symfony, fedora, assetic

After Updating my Fedora 24 to 25, the official php version went from [5.6 to 7.0.](http://doc.fedora-fr.org/wiki/Installation_et_configuration_de_PHP)
So I installed the older version to have both available (via [Remi Depo](http://rpms.remirepo.net/fedora/))

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.13 (cli) (built: Nov 25 2016 06:03:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

$ php56 -v
PHP 5.6.29 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2016 07:55:50) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

I re install node, nodejs and less to have a clean install.

```
dnf install node nodejs
npm install -g less
```

But since I can't run the symfony 2 assetic command:
(running it with php or php56 doesn't change the output)

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump
Dumping all dev assets.
Debug mode is on.

16:06:19 [file+] /var/www/project/app/../web/css/5a72185.css


  [Assetic\Exception\FilterException]                                                                                                                                                     
  An error occurred while running:                                                                                                                                                        
  'node' '/tmp/assetic_lessjBxrsP'                                                                                                                                                        
  Error Output:                                                                                                                                                                           
  NameError: #grid > .core > .span is undefined in /var/www/project/vendor/mopa/bootstrap-bundle/Mopa/Bundle/BootstrapBundle/Resources/bootstrap/less/navbar.less on line 199, column 3:  
  198 .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {                                                                                                                                                   
  199   #grid > .core > .span(@gridColumns);                                                                                                                                              
  200 }                                                                                                                                                                                   
  Input:                                                                                                                                                                                  
  /*!                                                                                                                                                                                     
   * MopaBootstrapBundle                                                                                                                                                                  
   *                                                                                                                                                                                      
   * Copyright 2011 Mohrenweiser & Partner                                                                                                                                                
   * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0                                                                                                                                               
   * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0                                                                                                                                           
   *                                                                                                                                                                                      
   * Import this file in your less files as first to be abled to access less vars from your file                                                                                          
   * OR                                                                                                                                                                                   
   * Add it to the stylesheets of assetic or                                                                                                                                              
   * Add it as described on http://www.lesscss.org with the less.js (maybe pathes must be adapted in that case)                                                                           
   *                                                                                                                                                                                      
   * Be careful when using less this way, might be most straight forward, but assetic doesnt check the included files                                                                     
   * for changes, and will only regenerate the css if it detects changes in this file!                                                                                                    
   *                                                                                                                                                                                      
   * For development it might be easier to include all you less files in the layout directly                                                                                              
   * But then assetic will compile each less file in a own compiler session so you cant mix in the less style into bootstrap, which might not be OK                                       
   */                                                                                                                                                                                     
  // Main bootstrap.less entry point                                                                                                                                                      
  @import "../../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";                                                                                                                                          
  // variables                                                                                                                                                                            
  @iconSpritePath:       "/bundles/mopabootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png";                                                                                                           
  @iconWhiteSpritePath:  "/bundles/mopabootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";                                                                                                     
  // The Paginator less for MopaBootstrapBundle                                                                                                                                           
  @import "paginator.less";                                                                                                                                                               
  // The Subnav less for MopaBootstrapBundle                                                                                                                                              
  @import "subnav.less";                                                                                                                                                                  
  // Collection support for MopaBootstrapBundle                                                                                                                                           
  @import "collections.less";                                                                                                                                                             
  // Collection support for MopaBootstrapBundle                                                                                                                                           
  @import "google-maps.less";                                                                                                                                                             
  // if you have any variables.less file INCLUDE IT AFTER EVERYTHING cause responsive.less also overrides it with the one from bootstrap!!!!!                                             


assetic:dump [--forks FORKS] [--watch] [--force] [--period PERIOD] [--] [<write_to>]
```

Why is the assetic command not working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fedora upgrade might have updated your Less version and it is no longer working with your project.

Try to install and use an older version like the 1.7.5.

`sudo npm install -g less@1.7.5`